# Magento 2 how to save values to multiple tables

Tags: magento-2.1.7

I have 2 custom table and from admin side I want to save few field values to these 2 custom table while clicking Save button. For example in adminside I have Status option and Message option. The Status option value need to be in custom table 1 and message in custom table 2. How can I do this in Magento 2. I have Save.php file in Controller/Adminhtml/Manage folder.

Comment: Have you created two models for two tables ?

Comment: Yes I have created 2 models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller constructor would be like

```
public function __construct(Action\Context $context,Package\Module\Model\Model1 $model1 , Package\Module\Model\Model2 $model2)
{
    $this->model1 = $model1;
    $this->model2 = $model2;
    parent::__construct($context);
}


public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue(); 
    $this->model1->setData('fieldname',$data['status']);
    $this->model1->save();

    $this->model2->setData('fieldname',$data['messageOption']);
    $this->model2->save();
}
```